# syntax error for if statement in shell script

Tags: shell

I have been getting this error for about an hour now. It says:

if: Expression Syntax

when I try to run my shell script. I could not find the problem in the code so I shortened everything down to this simple conditional:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo "ERROR - no arguments given"
exit 1
fi
```

I have looked all over the internet and this syntax appears to be flawless.. So why do I still get the if expression syntax error???

Comment: im not sure. i am using a terminal that my school manages. is there a command to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using csh/tcsh, so you have to write

```
if ( $# == 0 ) then
  echo "ERROR - no arguments given"
  exit 1
endif
```

(With bash your script runs ok here)

Comment: hmmm idk how you knew that but thanks a lot! Actually the first part is right but instead of endif, i still needed fi. No idea why. My professor taught us the wrong syntax to everything

Comment: He probably taught you sh and your error is that you use a different shell. They are similar, but still, it's sort of like complaining that the Prolog compiler won't accept C.

Comment: @Matt guessed it because it works perfect with bash and the error-msg looks like csh. But that fi your shell wants makes me curious: which system and shell are you using exactly?